# How to install ubuntu on a macbook pro using a pendrive?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, usb-flash-drive, macbook

I did an upgrade of 11.04 into 13.04 and it has failed miserably.

Now I want a fresh install, hopefully saving my /home directory. I use centos on my other machine and do not have access to a macos anymore.

What I was able to figure out some time ago (sorry no links):

I need to create a dmg image of an ordinary .iso install image. [libdmg-hfsplus](https://github.com/planetbeing/libdmg-hfsplus) will do it it seems.

I should copy this onto a vfat-formatted pendrive partition with dd while the pendrive is not mounted.

When putting the pendrive into the macbook, I should hold ctrl while booting and then macbook will allow to boot from the pendrive.

I did not succeed so I ask: are the above correct and sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My MacBook Pro can boot from USB drives created with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) from an original Ubuntu iso.

If the mac boot-manager still doesn't see it, you might want to consider installing [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).

Hope this helps.